# How do you prove this tensor identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

Suppose we have a tensor field ${\Gamma_{ab}}^{c}$ on a smooth manifold $M$ such that for all vector fields $X^a$, we have $X^aX^b{\Gamma_{ab}}^{[c}X^{d]} = 0$.
How do you show that there exists a 1-form field $\Upsilon_a$ such that ${\Gamma_{(ab)}}^c = \Upsilon_a {\delta_b}^c + \Upsilon_b {\delta_a}^c$, where ${\delta_a}^b$ is the identity endomorphism of $TM$?

Comment: Is ${\Gamma_{ab}}^{[c}X^{d]} = {\Gamma_{ab}}^{c}X^{d}-{\Gamma_{ab}}^{d}X^{c}$?

Comment: Yeah; the square brackets denote antisymmetrisation, and the round brackets denote symmetrisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first observation is that the assumption and the conclusion does not depends on differentiation, thus this is a pointwise statement and has nothing to do with the smooth manifold $M$. We just need to prove the statement at a point.

Now we think of $\Gamma$ as a multilinear map

$$ \Gamma : V\times V \to V.$$

Then the condition is the same as saying that

$$\Gamma(X, X) \otimes X = X\otimes \Gamma(X, X).$$

Thus there is $\lambda :V\to \mathbb R$ so that

$$\Gamma(X, X) = \lambda (X) X$$

for all $X\in V$. Note that one has $\lambda(aX) = a\lambda (X)$.

Now we investigate the property of $\lambda$. Now write $S(X, Y) = \Gamma(X, Y) + \Gamma(Y, X)$, then we have

$$(*)\ \ S(X, Y)= (\lambda(X+Y) - \lambda(X))X + (\lambda(X+Y) - \lambda(Y))Y.$$

If $\lambda$ is linear, then the require expression is shown by letting $\Upsilon = \lambda$.

*Claim* $\lambda$ is linear.

From $(*)$, using $X\mapsto -X$, we have

$$ -S(X, Y)= (\lambda(-X+Y) - \lambda(-X))(-X) + (\lambda(-X+Y) - \lambda(Y))Y.$$

Comparing coefficient of $Y$ gives

$$\lambda(X+Y) - \lambda(Y) = -\lambda(-X +Y) + \lambda(Y), $$

which is the same as

$$\lambda(X+Y) + \lambda(Y-X) = 2\lambda(Y),$$

Put $X = \frac{v-u}{2}, Y = \frac{v+u}{2}$, then

$$\lambda (v) + \lambda(u) = \lambda(u+v).$$

Thus $\lambda$ is linear.